Oracle APex Add custom grid reset button to revert any data changes
I have an Interactive Grid.
Howevere here i had to hide Apex Row Selector and Row Actions features.
I have a page process that inserts and deletes rows on click of custom save button.
Usually if a person doesnt want to save change they would simply refresh the page .
But i have requirement to add a Cancel button which would reset the grid data.
If i add a simple button that submits the page, it works only during update. If i insert new record it will throw validation errors since i have not null column validations.
Any suggestions as to how this can be configured?
Version- 22.1

Why would you want to reinvent the wheel? Teach users to use options that already exist.
What you want is in "Actions - Data - Refresh":


Thanks it is helpful. But they are adamant on an extra button. Will still try convincing them otherwise!

Refresh being the straightforward solution, giving you in addition the below code in case you (or future readers) would need the 'revert any changes' in the sense of cancelling and resetting the grid data without roundtrip to the server.
Initialization JavaScript Function:
function(config) { 
    let toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();
    let toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3");
    let revertAllCtrl = {
        "type":"BUTTON", 
        "action":"revert-all", 
        "label":"Revert All"
    }; 
    toolbarGroup.controls.push(revertAllCtrl); 
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData; 
    config.initActions = function (actions) { 
        actions.add({ 
            name: 'revert-all', 
            action: function(event, focusElement) { 
                let currentView = $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getCurrentView');
                let model = currentView.model;
                let changes = model.getChanges();
                model.revertRecords(changes.filter((recMeta)=>recMeta.updated||recMeta.deleted).map((recMeta) => recMeta.record));
                model.deleteRecords(changes.filter((recMeta)=>recMeta.inserted).map((recMeta) => recMeta.record));
                currentView.curInst.inEditMode() ? currentView.curInst.setEditMode(false) : null;
            } 
        }); 
    };     
    return config; 
}

If needed, 'Are you sure' question to be added.

Check this blog. It shows how to customize the toolbar - you can add a button and reference an existing action (in your case "refresh").
